# The report server is unable to access encrypted data. Apply a back-up key or delete all encrypted content.

Tags: sql-server, encryption, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have failure on a main production server, so stand by server kicked in without data loss. 
But when I run my SSRS reports I have this error

`The report server is unable to access encrypted data. Apply a back-up key or delete all encrypted content.`

[image]

I already restored my encryption key, but I still experiencing the problem.
I have lots of subscriptions, and I am trying to find a way not to delete all of them.

Could you please help?
Thanks

Comment: Try it's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/ssrs-encryption-keys-delete-and-re-create-encryption-keys

Comment: So if I recreate encryption key I wont lose all the subscriptions I already have?